# changing data to xml

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, pdf-generation

I have been tasked with finishing a demo for a client as our main developer is currently unavailable. All the programming experience I have is that I briefly crossed swords with C# 5 years ago but haven't used it since.

I need help with turning exported data into XML if that makes sense. Currently we have a build which takes a PDF form extracts the required data which is shown to work via command prompt. I need to be able to turn this data into XML, so it can be queried to a database. The idea of the program is to take required data from a PDF convert it to XML and query it to a database where the data is stored. We are using the C# language in conjunction with the iTextsharp library. I would post the code but I'm not allowed to.

So I am asking can anyone help me out? Maybe point me towards an example of how this is done and or explain as simply as possible how I would go about doing this? I wouldn't usually ask for help from others but because the fact I haven't coded in years, it has left me feeling intimidated.

Comment: One option would be to create classes that mimic your data (i.e. fields/properties), create objects for each "entity" in your PDF data and serialize your objects to XML. There is a large number of examples in XML serialization on StackOverflow and on MSDN. The main idea would be to create a buffer (class objects) where you could structure the data you are receiving from your PDFs.

Comment: If the end product your client wants is the data in the database, why are you putting it into XML first?

Comment: I really can't tell you why as this is apart of a bigger picture and doing it this way enables us to use the code for other more important things.

Comment: Is the data always tabular? Just a p.s. I would ensure that the pdf parsing is as desired, e.g. bold text can sometimes appear twice when parsing a PDF.

Comment: One last point.... you should say which DB you are intending to store the XML in, and is it desired to store the XML file itself or just the data?

Comment: I was informed we would be using the SQlite library and it is only the XML data I need hosted on the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may prove usefull to you... Taken from [a way to parse PDF data using iTextSharp](http://forums.asp.net/p/1583100/3994231.aspx)

```
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text;

private void openPDF()
{
    string str = "";
    string newFile = "c:\\New Document.pdf";
    Document doc = new Document();

    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("c:\\New Document.pdf");
    for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
    {
        byte[] bt = reader.GetPageContent(i);
        str += ExtractTextFromPDFBytes(bt);
    }
}

private string ExtractTextFromPDFBytes(byte[] input)
{
    if (input == null || input.Length == 0) return "";

    try
    {
        string resultString = "";

        // Flag showing if we are we currently inside a text object
        bool inTextObject = false;


        // Flag showing if the next character is literal
        // e.g. '\\' to get a '\' character or '\(' to get '('
        bool nextLiteral = false;


        // () Bracket nesting level. Text appears inside ()
        int bracketDepth = 0;


        // Keep previous chars to get extract numbers etc.:
        char[] previousCharacters = new char[_numberOfCharsToKeep];
        for (int j = 0; j < _numberOfCharsToKeep; j++) previousCharacters[j] = ' ';

        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            char c = (char)input[i];

            if (inTextObject)
            {
                // Position the text
                if (bracketDepth == 0)
                {
                    if (CheckToken(new string[] { "TD", "Td" }, previousCharacters))
                    {
                        resultString += "\n\r";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (CheckToken(new string[] { "'", "T*", "\"" }, previousCharacters))        {
                            resultString += "\n";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (CheckToken(new string[] { "Tj" }, previousCharacters))
                            {
                                resultString += " ";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                // End of a text object, also go to a new line.
                if (bracketDepth == 0 && CheckToken(new string[] { "ET" }, previousCharacters))
                {
                    inTextObject = false;
                    resultString += " ";
                }
                else
                {
                    // Start outputting text
                    if ((c == '(') && (bracketDepth == 0) && (!nextLiteral))
                    {
                        bracketDepth = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Stop outputting text
                        if ((c == ')') && (bracketDepth == 1) && (!nextLiteral))
                        {
                            bracketDepth = 0;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Just a normal text character:
                            if (bracketDepth == 1)
                            {
                                // Only print out next character no matter what.
                                // Do not interpret.
                                if (c == '\\' && !nextLiteral)
                                {
                                    nextLiteral = true;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if (((c >= ' ') && (c <= '~')) || ((c >= 128) && (c < 255)))
                                    {
                                        resultString += c.ToString();
                                    }


                                    nextLiteral = false;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


            // Store the recent characters for
            // when we have to go back for a checking
            for (int j = 0; j < _numberOfCharsToKeep - 1; j++)
            {
                previousCharacters[j] = previousCharacters[j + 1];
            }

            previousCharacters[_numberOfCharsToKeep - 1] = c;

            // Start of a text object
            if (!inTextObject && CheckToken(new string[] { "BT" }, previousCharacters))
            {
                inTextObject = true;
            }
        }

        return resultString;
    }
    catch
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}


private bool CheckToken(string[] tokens, char[] recent)
{
   foreach (string token in tokens)
   {
      if ((recent[_numberOfCharsToKeep - 3] == token[0]) &&
       (recent[_numberOfCharsToKeep - 2] == token[1]) &&
       ((recent[_numberOfCharsToKeep - 1] == ' ') ||
       (recent[_numberOfCharsToKeep - 1] == 0x0d) ||
       (recent[_numberOfCharsToKeep - 1] == 0x0a)) &&
       ((recent[_numberOfCharsToKeep - 4] == ' ') ||
       (recent[_numberOfCharsToKeep - 4] == 0x0d) ||
       (recent[_numberOfCharsToKeep - 4] == 0x0a)))
       {
                return true;
       }
    }

    return false;
 }
```

Once the data is parsed it's then a matter of converting each line to a class (as recommended by Andrei V in your post's comment), serializing it to XML and then storing either the XML file itself to the database or the XML data to the database.